# How do I send a user to a URL with push notification

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I use Microsoft's appcenter for my applications and want to send out a notification to all of my users containing custom data to push them to a URL.

I've tried looking at the documentation and can't seem to figure it out...

How do I do this via appcenter's UI?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Send the URL in a custom data object included with your notification, you can see an example of custom data here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/send-notification#compose. In the client application, pull the custom data object off the notification, grab the URL and do whatever you want to do with it.